# $\int\limits_{0}^{t}(\exp{(\sqrt{x}-x^2)} )^ \text{erf(x)}\ \text{d}x,$ VS golden ratio For $t\geq 2$ ,

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, approximation, golden-ratio

I have tried to get aother integral representation for the Golden ratio i have got the following representation . This integral is defined as : $$I(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}(\exp{(\sqrt{x}-x^2)} )^ \text{erf(x)}\ \text{d}x,$$ and this gives  $1.618...$ for $t  \to +\infty$  with approximation of $10^{-3}$ as shown here in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_%7B0%7D%5E%7Binfty%7D+((e%5E((sqrt(x)))e%5E(-x%C2%B2)+))%5E(erf(x))dx) and it's seems that is closed nicely  to Golden ratio for $t \in [2,3]$ for instance we have $t=2.75..$ and also for $t=e$  , Now my question here is :

**Question:** Is it possible to say that :For $t\geq 2$ ,$\int\limits_{0}^{t}(\exp{(\sqrt{x}-x^2)} )^ \text{erf(x)}\ \text{d}x$   could be another integral representation of Golden ratio ?

Comment: `t=2.7495392638089838109896679573104092694836858310585` with approximation of $\frac{1}{10^{50}}$

Comment: Thanks for this approximation

Comment: Write `$x^2$` instead of `$x²$`

Comment: `t` seems pretty arbitrary.

Comment: For $t=+\infty$ Mma evaluates the integral as $1.6185270961489910965842\ldots$ which is  $0.000493107399\ldots$ more than the Golden ratio. Seems like not much of an approximation.